# Create icon with inkscape and import it with material ui SvgIcon

Tags: reactjs, svg, material-ui, inkscape

I just created an icon in inkscape. Like mentioned [here](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#svgicon) I set the viewport to 24x24 and I saved it as a svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.0 (4035a4fb49, 2020-05-01)"
   id="svg16"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 6.3499999 6.3499997"
   height="24"
   width="24">
  <defs
     id="defs10" />

  <sodipodi:namedview
     lock-margins="true"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     units="px"
     showborder="true"
     inkscape:snap-nodes="true"
     inkscape:snap-others="true"
     inkscape:object-nodes="false"
     inkscape:snap-object-midpoints="false"
     inkscape:snap-midpoints="false"
     inkscape:guide-bbox="true"
     showguides="true"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:window-y="37"
     inkscape:window-x="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1041"
     inkscape:window-width="1916"
     inkscape:object-paths="false"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:cy="15.424759"
     inkscape:cx="14.537256"
     inkscape:zoom="22.627417"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     id="base" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata13">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
    <g
         transform="translate(74.493643,27.309445)"
         style="opacity:0.954874"
         id="layer1"
         inkscape:groupmode="layer"
         inkscape:label="Layer 1">
        <path
           d="m -74.493643,-24.6269 v 3.667168 h 3.166867 V -24.6269 Z m 1.366019,0.339834 h 0.434813 v 0.257505 h -0.434813 z"
           style="opacity:1;fill:#000000;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.0185523;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
           id="rect1057" />
        <path
           sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc"
           id="path1065"
           style="opacity:1;fill:#000000;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.0185523;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
           d="m -71.310514,-24.626608 3.166871,-2.639198 v 3.667163 l -3.166871,2.639198 z" />
        <path
           d="m -71.357846,-27.309445 -3.115172,2.657264 h 3.166868 l 3.158511,-2.629412 z m 0.0046,0.125321 2.897601,0.02523 -2.850926,2.381387 h -2.858487 z"
           style="opacity:1;fill:#000000;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.0185523;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
           id="path1067" />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Now I want to use this Icon like I use a material ui icon. So I created a new file called logo and just pasted the whole svg file between `<SvgIcon>`. This didn't work because `sodipodi:nodetypes` for example throws an error. In addition the style should be an object and so on. So I cleaned the whole entries and only the paths are left. But no Icon is shown. So I deleted all paths but one to see at least something but nothing is shown.

```
import React from "react";
import SvgIcon from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";

const Logo = (props) => {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <path
        d="m 4.493643,-24.00 v 3.667168 h 3.166867 V -24.000 Z m 1.366019,0.339834 h 0.434813 v 0.257505 h -0.434813 z"
        id="rect1057" />
    </SvgIcon>
  )
}
export default Logo;
```

Maybe someone can describe the whole process how this is done correctly. And what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could solve it by myself:

1. Create your icon inkscape
2. Save as "Optimized SVG and check Export as SVG 1.1 per settings in Preference Dialog
3. check the following at the options:

- Shorten color values
- Convert CSS attributes to XML attributes
- Collapse groups
- Create groups for similar attributes

4. SVG Output:

- Remove the XML declaration
- Remove metadata
- Remove comments
- Format output with line-breaks and indentation

5. Save the file and open it with for example nvim
6. Copy everything between the `<svg>` tags
7. create an file for the icon (icon.js)

code:

```
import React from "react";
import SvgIcon from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";

const MyIcon = ({ color }) => {
  const memorizedIcon = React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <SvgIcon viewBox={"0 0 52.916665 52.91667"}>
        // YOUR ICON
      </SvgIcon>
    );
  }, [color]);

  return memorizedIcon;
};

export default MyIcon;
```

8. Copy the viewbox from the svg file to the code
9. transform the style annotations from `style="something-tag: something"` to `style={{somethingTag: "something"}}`

Done

Comment: I think you can use the XML editor in Inkscape to add the correct viewbox of "0 0 24 24". It's a good idea to save an inkscape document with all the correct settings as a template. I would recommend fitting some existing icons into your inkscape view to set up guides so that your icon will work side by side with the standard mui icons.

Comment: Thank you for this, I've spent days looking for the answer.